# Microservice design pattern: communication between microservices

Tags: microservices

Im not really sure how to describe the title of my question but im currently looking into the microservice design pattern and have read some microsoft documentation and some videos on pluralsight. What I read is that its not a wrong pattern to have duplication of data. Meaning that for example if i have a identity microservice holding user data and a forum microservice that its not "wrong" to save a part of the user object from the identity microservice in the forum microservice, for example the users displayname.
Good to mention that both microservices have their own database.

What I cant seem to find though is that what if in the example given the user changes his/hers display name. I see two options i guess:

1. Dont store display name and store a user id, and have the forum microservice call the identity microservice to retrieve displayname. Problem about this is that the microservice databases are not related so if a user is deleted you can get weird behavior.
2. If a user changes displayname fire a event to the Forum microservice to change do a update. This could for example be done with a message bus.

I think the message bus(option 2) would be the most suitable but I was wondering if im maybe missing other options?

Answer (score 0):

There are trade off for both and you catch the main issue with one pretty well, go with your instincts I would say.

I would avoid data duplication and just store keys for some of the exact reasons you mentioned.  Then you have to do multiple updates across services when just some data changes, but now you have to check all your dependencies when anything changes.  Plus now your data isn't really managed by its micro service but 1 or many services.

If its data that changes a bunch, but retrieved by other services a bunch as well you could look into caching and setting up some publish/subscribe mechanism.  I know that is what we are going to look at soon. Other things we have done is setup dblinks between databases and created views to better link data on the backend for micro services.  This was to get around setting up publish/subscribe, it works but has its own issues.

Another thing I would say to invest in is how you communicate between your services, this will solve most of your issues.  We went with [protocol-buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers) and we love it.